# Is there a way to limit only allow incoming requests from other App Engine services?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have four services running within the same app on App Engine. I have a frontend SvelteKit application, and three backend services. If possible, I'd like to set up security in such a way that the backend services will only accept HTTP requests from the frontend application (which sends all API requests via its Node server).

Is there a way of doing this without spending a load of money on a Serverless VPC Access connector?

Ideally I want to keep these all within the same GCP project as well. So far the only solution I can come up with is to ship the services with a secret that they check against when receiving a request, but there must be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take a look at [Identity Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authenticate-users-google-accounts#iap-access)
2. Pay attention to the part of the above documentation that says

> In order to make a resource publicly-accessible (while sibling resources are restricted), grant the IAP-secured Web App User role to `allUsers` or `allAuthenticatedUsers`.

3. Per your use case, your front-end application will be available to the public while your 3 backend services will only be available to the front-end application
4. Since your backend services are now secured (via IAP), you have to programmatically invoke them in your front end. See [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#obtaining_an_oidc_token_for_the_default_service_account) on how to do that.