# How to restrict access to goole app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I have in the same project 2 flex app engine instances and i want to restrict the access to them. Both are in the same vpc network and both have the same vpc_access_connector.

Currently anybody can access both instances and the ip of the visitor is always the same.
I tried to use the vpc firewall rules to restrict access, but it didn't work, because as i mentioned the ip of the visitor is always the same.

I want services from the same or other projects to be able to access those 2 instances and also to have access from my local machine.

However, i want also to apply different restriction rules to each app engine instance.

Is there a way to achieve that ?

Comment: It sounds to me like your first request is just equal to the internal setting on the ingress https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ingress-settings#settings. Please clarify what kind of restriction rules you are thinking off for the second request. But in any case it might be worth looking into migrating to cloud run and making use of IAM permissions for service accounts to restrict access (which appengine flex doesnt support afaik).

Comment: Is it possible to achieve what i want with IAP ? What i want is to remove public access from my app engine instances. I want the nodes of kubernetes cluster from another project to be able to send requests to the app engine instances. Additionally i want to be able to send requests to the app engine insntances using postman from my local machine.

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73347975/is-there-a-way-to-limit-only-allow-incoming-requests-from-other-app-engine-servi/73348551#73348551