# How to use App Engine Firewall to only accept traffic from website

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, firewall

I am creating an API for my website in App Engine. I want to restrict the API to only allows requests from my home computer and the website. I already Denied * ip addresses. I added my home ip address for development. How do I add my website?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the same output using a different approach

1. Create a service for the API. This means your App Engine project will have 2 services - one for your website (i.e. default/frontend) and another for the API
2. Turn on [Identity Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authenticate-users-google-accounts#iap-access). Make your default service publicly accessible and then restrict the API service to your default service. For how to do this, see the stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73347975/is-there-a-way-to-limit-only-allow-incoming-requests-from-other-app-engine-servi/73348551#73348551)
3. The above solution should also work for your home computer because your home computer will be running your default service which is the one invoking your API service. You could also just write separate code that will generate the token required to invoke your service (as described in the link above)